# Trying to perform transposed convolution but missing a pixel

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensor, deconvolution

```
def get_unet(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=0.5, batchnorm=True):

    # contracting path
    c1 = conv2d_block(input_img, n_filters=n_filters * 1, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)
    p1 = Dropout(dropout * 0.5)(p1)

    c2 = conv2d_block(p1, n_filters=n_filters * 2, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
    p2 = Dropout(dropout)(p2)

    c3 = conv2d_block(p2, n_filters=n_filters * 4, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
    p3 = Dropout(dropout)(p3)

    c4 = conv2d_block(p3, n_filters=n_filters * 8, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
    p4 = Dropout(dropout)(p4)

    c5 = conv2d_block(p4, n_filters=n_filters * 16, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    # expansive path
    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 8, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    u6 = Dropout(dropout)(u6)
    c6 = conv2d_block(u6, n_filters=n_filters * 8, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 4, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    u7 = Dropout(dropout)(u7)
    c7 = conv2d_block(u7, n_filters=n_filters * 4, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 2, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    u8 = Dropout(dropout)(u8)
    c8 = conv2d_block(u8, n_filters=n_filters * 2, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 1, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    u9 = Dropout(dropout)(u9)
    c9 = conv2d_block(u9, n_filters=n_filters * 1, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[outputs])
    return model
```

I got this model for Keras from here. I seem to be getting the error:

```
  File "train.py", line 87, in get_unet
  u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 256, 184, 32), (None, 256, 185, 32)]
```

So I printed the values of each of these Tensors, and I got:

```
c1: Tensor("activation_2/Relu:0", shape=(?, 512, 370, 16), dtype=float32)
c2: Tensor("activation_4/Relu:0", shape=(?, 256, 185, 32), dtype=float32)
c3: Tensor("activation_6/Relu:0", shape=(?, 128, 92, 64), dtype=float32)
c4: Tensor("activation_8/Relu:0", shape=(?, 64, 46, 128), dtype=float32)
c5: Tensor("activation_10/Relu:0", shape=(?, 32, 23, 256), dtype=float32)
u6: Tensor("dropout_5/cond/Merge:0", shape=(?, 64, 46, 256), dtype=float32)
u7: Tensor("dropout_6/cond/Merge:0", shape=(?, 128, 92, 128), dtype=float32)
u8: Tensor("conv2d_transpose_3/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 32), dtype=float32)
```

What happened at `C2`? Why is the second dimension of `u8` 184, while the second dimension of `C2` seems to be 185. Furthermore, `C3`s second dimension seems to to be maxpooled by a factor of 2 from 184 (probably due to a `floor` function)

How would I combat this? Do I have to change the size of the images that are being inputted, or do I have to engineer something while doing the transpose convolution? Do I need to perform interpolation for the one extra pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because your second dimension is not even when you divide it by 2 in your C2 layer.
You are maxpooling 185 by a factor of 2, which gives you 92.5 -> floor to 92
But when you do the operation in the other way, you are upsampling 92 by a factor of 2 which gives you 184.

To avoid this you can simply zeropad U8 to be compatible with C2, like this :

```py
u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 2, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0, 0), (0, 1)))(u8)
u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
```

If you don't want to zeropad, you can reshape your input images in order to have a dimension corresponding to a power of 2 or a dimension that can be divided by two multiple times without giving an odd number, like 224 (can be divided by two 5 times before giving 7).

Hope that will help you !

Comment: After adding the zero padding, I get `ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 258, 186, 32), (None, 256, 185, 32)]` still

Comment: Did a little bit of research and I think your answer should be: `u8 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0, 0), (0, 1)))(u8)`

Comment: Yes that's my bad, i writed too fast without think that will pad all your image .. You need to gain only one pixel so that's right

Comment: Can you also go over the advantages and disadvantages of zero padding as compared to an image resize (in terms of image segmentation) and I shall accept your answer!

Comment: Actually in your case, adding only one pixel of 0s will have no influence on your image, it's way too small, so it's the simplest way to do this.
The disadvantages can comes when the zeroppading is bigger and start to modify the structure of your image.
With the resize you can loose information, but keep it's structure so it will depend of the problem